# Why using mke2fs -j creates ext3 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-from-scratch

-j
Creates the filesystem with an ext3 journal.

Why not an ext4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [ext3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) is ext2fs with a journal (and the original [ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) does not support a journal), if you want ext4 use `mkfs.ext4` or even `mkfs.ext4dev`. From the ext2 wiki,

> ... supplanted more recently by ext3, which is almost completely compatible with ext2 and is a journaling file system.